# Narrowing TypeScript disjoint union with literal type guard works in function, but not on React state

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I have a reducer with a nextAction state that works as sort of a callback. The NextAction is typed like so:

```
type NextActionSave = {type: 'save'};
type NextActionSaveAndSet = {type: 'saveAndSet', name: TextFieldName, value: string};
type NextAction = NextActionSave | NextActionSaveAndSet;
interface EditRowState {
  ...
  nextAction: NextAction | null;
}
```

In another file, I have a switch statement on state.nextAction.type

```
import React from 'react';
import {EditRowState, EditRowAction, NextAction} from './reducer';

interface Props {
  save: () => Promise<void>;
  state: EditRowState;
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<EditRowAction>;
}

const useNextAction = (props: Props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    executeNextAction(props.state.nextAction);
  }, [props.state.nextAction]);

  const executeNextAction = (nextAction: NextAction | null) => {
    if (nextAction === null) return;

    switch(nextAction.type) {
      case 'save':
        props.save();
        break;
      case 'saveAndSet':
        props.save().then(() => {
          const {name, value} = nextAction;
          props.dispatch({type: 'set', name, value, advance: true});
        });
      default: return;
    }
  };
};
```

This works. [Here is a TypeScript Playground of the executeNextAction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAchAewCCBjYBLA9gOwMoEMA3aAXigG8pRIAuKAcgGciJ6oBfAbgFgAoBMJgBOwKuGhxEqDDgLEk2ACa4IospWoQ6TFguWr6AGijZ8AWy1RGwIemwBzY4XwAbAK6Xrthxx69NsAjIaFjYUGSSwTJ4LFAAPoFSIbK6SirAfnwAZm7YyWEIEChuwBCR0qEAFNhBFTh05fkAlBR8UFDoWVDVtfnhJGTYbi4uLUKqbkLYfu1tVgDu6MAoABbdNUnRAHSaLeRz7Sj4jNA6xPQ0B+1QKDiMmC4QWy6Y9pVn0IvAK5glVqoYHzfaAbUTWfClehNK7tABG43wAGsZtcjicGMx5GkDJdeNdroslJh5lsTsAACroCy-YCVSotEgAPlaePxqLuokopgsTlcHg44RMvWiKLZNzuDyeLzeZzs9ig+CU-1EbAA1CZzNB1WxgJgGFB1c53BAmqLruxoaz2Hx2EA) showing the executeNextAction function.

If I move the body of executeNextAction inside the useEffect, so that nextAction comes directly from the state, it says, "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'NextAction'". I get the same error for the value property. My code without a separate executeNextAction function is below. [Here is a simplified version of my code below in a TypeScript Playground showing the error.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchAewCCBjYBLA9gOwMoEMA3aAXigG8pRIAuKAcgGciJ6oBfAbgFgAoBMJgBOwKuGhxEqDDgLEk2ACa4IospWoQ6TFguWr6AGijZ8AWy1RGwIemwBzY4XwAbAK6Xrthxx69NsAjIaFjYUGSSwTJ4LFAAPoFSIbK6SirAfnx2wBBCAGb4KNC4wPg5FHxQJkHSoXSRtTjxJm4uLn7sfHx5btjJYQgQKG45Df0AFACUFbxVKDjWVqU5NCVlpBTYNf105JrazMT07J2zUOh5UOPW6wB0W0nR4SRk2K0u00KqbkLYflWVKwAd3QwBQAAsrjccvdttFbpppuRAXN8IxoDojjQUVUoPNsIxMC4ILcXJh7ONMdAQcBwZgRlZVBgfLToA9RNDWJMcVUAEZffAAa3+uJQaIxhwgenS9GxZ1xUBBSkwQNu6OAABV0BZ6cBxlNwgA+GYKhX4xaUUwWJyuDwccJLO7sxp-HmihZEklkimYuz2KD4JSM0RsADUJnM0HDbGAmAYUHDzncEEmIoV7G5Z1Opz4QA)

```
import React from 'react';
import {EditRowState, EditRowAction} from './reducer';

interface Props {
  save: () => Promise<void>;
  state: EditRowState;
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<EditRowAction>;
}

const useNextAction = (props: Props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (props.state.nextAction === null) return;

    switch(props.state.nextAction.type) {
      case 'save':
        props.save();
        break;
      case 'saveAndSet':
        props.save().then(() => {
          const {name, value} = props.state.nextAction;
          props.dispatch({type: 'set', name, value, advance: true});
        });
      default: return;
    }
  }, [props.state.nextAction]);
};
```

It works if I typecast props.state.nextAction using `as NextActionSaveAndSet`. It looks like the switch statement acts as a [literal type guard](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard#literal-type-guard), so I shouldn't need the type cast. I'm guessing this is why it works in the version where I moved the code into a executeNextAction function. What's the difference between using nextAction as a function parameter or accessing it on the state? Would I be able to use it on the state if I added an `as const` somewhere?

Comment: Please consider editing this code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/qNBpVW) so that others can demonstrate the issue for themselves. It *looks* like you are narrowing a value via control flow analysis before `save()` is called, and then asynchronously doing something with that value later in a callback; at that point the compiler cannot assume the narrowing is still in effect (this is [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)). But without a [mcve] it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to properly explain why this works, but I have two different solutions which don't involve assertion.

1. Save `this.props.nextAction` to a variable.

```
const useNextAction = (props: Props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const {nextAction} = props.state;
    if (nextAction === null) return;

    switch(nextAction.type) {
      case 'save':
        props.save();
        break;
      case 'saveAndSet':
        props.save().then(() => {
          const {name, value} = nextAction;
          props.dispatch({type: 'set', name, value, advance: true});
        });
      default: return;
    }
  }, [props.state.nextAction]);
};
```

2. Destructure `name` and `value` outside of the callback

```
const useNextAction = (props: Props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (props.state.nextAction === null) return;

    switch(props.state.nextAction.type) {
      case 'save':
        props.save();
        break;
      case 'saveAndSet':
        const {name, value} = props.state.nextAction;
        props.save().then(() => {
          props.dispatch({type: 'set', name, value, advance: true});
        });
      default: return;
    }
  }, [props.state.nextAction]);
};
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w8vBEm)